# Getting Min/Max over multiple columns timestamp based

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to determine how to get the min and max values before a change occurs in SQL (Snowflake). Here is the dataset:

```
TS                            Node      Person
2022-11-29 12:01:00 AM        1         Adam
2022-11-29 12:02:00 AM        1         Adam
2022-11-29 12:03:00 AM        1         Adam
2022-11-29 12:04:00 AM        2         Adam
2022-11-29 12:05:00 AM        2         Adam
2022-11-29 12:06:00 AM        1         Adam
```

What I am trying to get is the following:

```
Person    Node    Min TS                    Max TS                      Elapsed
Adam      1       2022-11-29 12:01:00 AM    2022-11-29 12:03:00 AM      2
Adam      2       2022-11-29 12:04:00 AM    2022-11-29 12:05:00 AM      1
Adam      1       2022-11-29 12:06:00 AM    Null                        Null
```

I have tried to RANK, but when I get to the second set of Node 1, it just continues the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to achieve with [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html) window function:

> Returns a window event number for each row within a window partition when the value of the argument expr1 in the current row is different from the value of expr1 in the previous row.

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT *, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(Node) OVER(PARTITION BY Person 
                                               ORDER BY TS) AS subgrp
 FROM tab
)
SELECT Person, MIN(Node) AS Node, MIN(TS) AS MIN_TS, MAX(TS) AS MAX_TS
FROM cte
GROUP BY Person, subgrp;
```